# Migrate Postgres DB when the source Postgres server is offline

Tags: postgresql, migrate, gentoo

So yea the title says it all, I need to somehow get the DBs form the source server to the new server, but the kicker is the old server is falling apart :P and is there a way I can just move it all to the new server and import it?

the old server just refuses to run Postgres anymore and i am almost certain that the version that was running on the old server is 8.4, and the new server is running 9.2, will that cause an issue?

this is what I get when i try to start Postgres on the old server,

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 start
* Use of the opts variable is deprecated and will be
* removed in the future.
* Please use extra_commands, extra_started_commands or extra_stopped_commands.
* Starting PostgreSQL ...
could not start server   [ !! ]
* ERROR: postgresql-8.4 failed to start
```

also I am running gentoo :)

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: so i installed 8.4 migrated the data folder over the the new server, and now the 8.4 postgresql will not start not sure what is going on. and in order to use `pg_upgrade` the server has to be run-able. the error i am getting is `DATA_DIR not set`, and i checked the `/etc/conf.d/postgresql-8.4` file and the pgdata vairable is set `# PostgreSQL's Database Directory
PGDATA="/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/data"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the data files directly, but you must use the same *major* version of PG on the destination server (e.g. 8.4.x - the "8.4" is the major).  Easiest way to check the version is via `psql -V`.

The upgrade procedure in this situation isn't too hard if you want to move up to a 9.x release.  You'll need to install 8.4 on the new server (either via a package or by hand), then you'll want to use the `pg_upgrade` tool to do the upgrade.  `pg_upgrade` comes with recent releases of PG, so expect to have two installations on the server during that time.

You can find the docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/pgupgrade.html).

Answer (score 0):

Attention ! On Gentoo, pg_upgrade will fail if your config files (postgresql.conf + pg_hba.conf) are *NOT* located in /var/lib/postgresql//data/. New installs are storing config files in /etc/postgresql- right now.

Before migrating, make sure you copied files from /etc/postgresql-/ to this directory of pg_upgrade will fail.